# In a dataframe, replace first 'n' entries of a column with other values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, data-munging

I have a dataframe with a column called 'household'. Household has 2000 rows of entries. Now, I want to replace the first 200 rows with some values, that I have in another column.

So the final result of 'household' would be, first 200 is the replaced rows, and rest of the 1800 rows would be the original rows.

I have tried `replace()`, `slice()`, but couldn't figure out a way to do it.

```
oneday<- read.csv("C:\hh.csv")
top <- oneday %<>% slice(1:10) %>% select("household")
oneday["household"]=top["household"] #this is the part that does not work
```

It can select the top 10 data as a list, but cannot replace the data to complete the column as required.

Any help would be amazing.

Edit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbGtQ.png)

So as shown in picture, the data from 2 to 7 are changed, and the remaining are the same. So, data from 2 to 7 are in another data frame, and the remaining are original data.

Comment: Hi, it’s not clear to me if the values you want to replace the old values with are in another data frame (question title) or another column (question body). Can you add a minimal dataset to your question?

Comment: As @AndreaM mentioned, it's unclear the format of your data. I just added both options to my answer. To provide a small reproducible example, then you can use `dput`. You can type `dput(head(oneday))` into the console, then paste the results into your question.

Comment: HI, sorry for the confusion. Both the values are in different data frames. I have added a picture. Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `ifelse` statement, so that if the row is equal to or less than 200, then you can replace the values using data from the other dataframe, and if not keep the `household` values.

```
library(dplyr)

oneday %>%
  mutate(household = ifelse(row_number() <= 200, OtherDF$datachange, household))
```

Example with `mtcars`

Here, I pull data from `iris` to replace in `mtcars`.

```
mtcars %>%
  head %>% 
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(row_number() <= 4, iris$Sepal.Length, mpg))
```

**Output**

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4          5.1   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag      4.9   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710         4.7   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive     4.6   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Or in base R you can just specify the rows and column and directly replace them:

```
oneday[2:7, "household"] <- top[2:7, "household"]
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted....thank you!!! i really appreciate it.